# Typeset a path with Windows environment variables in a footnote

Tags: footnotes, urls

I try to display a path including an evironment with:

```latex
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Lorem \path{C:\%HOMEPATH%\Documents\} ipsum\footnote{\path{{C:\%HOMEPATH%\Documents\}}.
\end{document}
```

However during compilation I get the following error message:

```
Runaway argument?
{ \path {C:\%HOMEPATH
! File ended while scanning use of \@footnotetext.
<inserted text>
                \par
```

Any Idea on how to display a path with environments in a footnote?

Comment: In TeX `%` and \ are special characters. Try with a backlash behind them.

Comment: First of please always show full examples, here we need to know where `\path` is actually defined. If it is from the `url` package, then `\path{C:\%HOMEPATH%\Documents\}` actually does work on my system, but not in a footnote as `\path` has to do a lot of trickery. You might get aways by predefining the path using `\urldef` see the `url` manual.

Comment: @daleif The `\urldef` from the `url` manual did the trick. My document wasn't using that package. Instead I used `hyperref` and that manual has no mention of `\path`. Thus I thought it was a TeX default command of some sort. Thanks.

Comment: `url` is probably autoloaded by `hyperref`. Now you also know why providing the minimal example is so important. We can mostly answer much much faster.